# Compare two files and print results to new text file

Tags: command-line, package-management, text-processing

I want to compare the list of packages in a computer with an authorized list that I have. How would I do that? Would the following work?

```
cd /home
touch authorizedlist.txt
(list contents) >> authorizedllist.txt
touch currentlist.txt
dpkg -l | cut -d ' ' -f3 | less >> currentlist.txt
touch difflist.txt
diff authorizedlist.txt currentlist.txt >> difflist.txt
```

Is there a way to both create a new text file and add contents to it in one command instead of doing touch then putting the text in? Also, is there a way to only print what is **unneeded** from the currentlist and not what is missing from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

- `touch` sets the modification timestamp of a given file to "now". If the given file doesn't yet exist, it is created. This is a common way to create empty files.
- The `>>` redirection *appends* output to a given file. Similar to `touch` it creates the file if it doesn't yet exist. But keep in mind, it *appends* data to an existing file.
- The `>` redirection *overwrites* a given file with the output of the preceeding command. If the file doesn't yet exist, it gets created. If it already exists, it gets truncated (that is: cleared or emptied) and then the output is written to it.
- `less` is a so called *pager*. That is: it is meant for interactive usage so you can browse through larger files and use <kbd>space</kbd> and <kbd>b</kbd> (beyond others) to go forwards and backwards in a file or command output. If you redirect the output of a command to a file anyway, you can (and should) omit the `less` call.

Put together:

```
cd /home
(list contents) > authorizedlist.txt
dpkg -l | cut -d ' ' -f3 > currentlist.txt
diff authorizedlist.txt currentlist.txt > difflist.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation; it was clear and very helpful!

Comment: What about for the last question I asked in my post?

Comment: @suomynonA (Actually that is a separate question that should be posted as such.) I don't know what you mean exactly. All lines in `currentlist` that are not in `authorizedlist` or just the other way round or something else?

Comment: yes, all lines in currentlist not in authorizedlist

Comment: @terrance Thank you :-) but the last question $(reverse Anonymous) refers to is _How to show lines in fileA that are not in fileB_.

Comment: Right, that is missing lines.  But what is unneeded lines defined as?

Comment: @Terrance See previous comment: _all lines in currentlist not in authorizedlist_. That would be `grep -F -f authorized-list -v current-list` I guess.

Comment: I think I understand it.  Unneeded = lines that are in current-list and not in authorized-list.